# KDE on Fedora 30 doesn't keep resolution

Tags: linux, display, fedora, resolution, kde

I've installed KDE Plasma on Fedora 30 Workstation. The resolution was at the lowest but attempting to change the value in System Settings does not work. The monitor supports the resolution. Upon pressing the apply button it sets the resolution but then reverts in a second. The resolutions work on GNOME and Deepin Desktop but not on KDE. Even setting the resolution with `xrandr -s 1920x1080` it will revert back after a second.

Comment: Did you install Fedora or a Fedora spin with KDE already integrated, or tried adding KDE yourself as an additional DE?  KDE has endless pieces, and the meta package in the repository typically doesn't contain everything.  Even with all the pieces, integrating it into the distro isn't trivial.  That's the reason Mint dropped KDE; it was eating their resources.  There used to be a Fedora spin called Korora, which incorporated KDE, but that project shut down for the same reason. (cont'd)

Comment: Your best bet to get up and running with KDE on Fedora without brain damage is to install a spin that has it already integrated.  Check out https://spins.fedoraproject.org/kde/

Comment: @fixer1234 I installed it from the default ISO provided, not a spin. Installed the KDE using dnf in terminal. Is there a difference? I'll try getting a spin

Comment: There's a difference.  KDE isn't like a software package, where you just specify the package name and tell the package manager to install it.  It's an endless collection of packages, many of which are not part of the meta package.  Even if you know every package, integration isn't simple.  There are different choices of supporting packages, and the chance for dependency conflicts.  What you see as the KDE version of a distro required a lot of work by the maintainers to integrate and customize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Its a module called KScreen that causes the automatic resolution change. It needs to be disabled in the service manager.

[Steps to stop KScreen module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150513/how-do-i-stop-kde-from-changing-my-screen-resolution)